# Implementing search for a file manager using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react & redux and trying to make a file manager. I want to implement search functionality for it. Here is how I am doing it as of now:

State (Store)

```
const initialState = {
  ...
  searchResultsList:[],
};
```

Action for updating the state (dispatched on change of search input field )

```
export function search(searchString, address) {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    if (searchString.trim() === '') {
      dispatch(refreshSearchResultList()); // clears the search results in store
    } else {
      searchFiles(searchString, address, file =>
        dispatch(addFileToSearchResults(file))
      );
    }
  };
}
```

searchFiles:

```
export default function searchFiles(name, currDir, func) {
  // name -> searched string
  // currDir -> current directory (since we need to search only in subfolders)
  // func -> dispatching an action to update the search results in store  

  fs.readdir(currDir, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => {
    for (let dir of files) {
      if (dir.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())) {
        func(dir)
      }
      if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        searchFiles(name, path.join(currDir, dir.name), func);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

So, Now if i search for a string say "a" and then press another key so that the value to search for is now "ab", js will actually wait for the searchFiles function to execute completely before starting to search for files with "ab" in their name. How do i stop the execution of first one immediately and start a new one? I could use a counter as search id and pass it to the function as well (so basically, search function will check the value of counter in store and compare it to its searchid before checking every file name), so that when new search is made , check will fail and i will return instead.
But i don't like this approach, Is there any way in which i could keep the structure as it is (currently the searchFiles function doesn't need to connect to store or check any state) and still get what i want? Or a completely different way of implementing this, as this looks like a newbie way of doing things, i would like to know how do experienced people make it.